# Spring MVC, Hibernate Validation, Form request is not validated

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I need some help about validations in spring mvc 4.3 and hibernate.
I have imported "hibernate-validator-6.0.3.Final.jar" and "validation-api-2.0.0.Final.jar" (part of "hibernate-validator-6.0.3.Final.jar").

**When i fill form with data (username and password), username and password is not validated so request point to index**

**User.java**

```
package invoice.user;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

public class User {

    @NotNull(message = "required")
    @Size(min = 3, max = 50, message = "Username incorrect")
    private String username;

    @NotNull(message = "required")
    @Size(min = 3, max = 50, message = "Password incorrect")
    private String password;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "username='" + username + '\'' +
                ", password='" + password + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**UserController.java**

```
package invoice.user;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import javax.validation.Valid;

@Controller
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String showLoginPage(@ModelAttribute("user") User user){
        return "user/user-login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processLoginForm(@Valid @ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult results){
        if(results.hasErrors()){
            return "user/user-login";
        }
            return "user/index";
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share more code related to configuration

Comment: I am new, what configuration should I share?

Comment: What do you need exactly..?

Answer (score 0):

In **UserController** ,**showLoginPage** will accept all the request and returns `user/user-login`.remove this then check

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processLoginForm(@Valid @ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult results){
        if(results.hasErrors()){
            return "user/user-login";
        }
            return "user/index";
    }
}
```